# error: incompatible types: Class<SplashViewModel> cannot be converted to Class<? extends NonExistentClass>

Tags: gradle, version, dagger

I have an error " incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Class<? extends NonExistentClass> "

Mb someone had the same problem

[what i've got during compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTNbW.png)

I think something wrong with my gradle/kotlin/dagger versions
It's my versions.gradle file

```
xt.deps = [:]
def versions = [:]
//versions.gradle_plugin = '3.4.0'
versions.gradle_plugin = '7.0.2'
versions.kotlin = "1.8.0"
versions.arch_core = "1.1.1"
versions.room = "2.4.2"
versions.lifecycle = "1.1.1"
versions.support = "28.0.0"
versions.constraintlayout = "2.0.4"
versions.multidex = "1.0.3"
versions.dagger = "2.+"
versions.test_runner = "1.0.2"
versions.junit = "4.12"
versions.espresso = "3.0.2"
versions.mockito = "2.+"
versions.mockitoKotlin = "1.6.0"
versions.rxjava2 = "2.2.2"
versions.rxandroid = "2.1.0"
versions.retrofit = "2.3.0"
versions.okhttp = "3.11.0"
versions.stetho = "1.5.0"
versions.glide = "4.8.0"
versions.coveralls = "2.8.1"
def deps = [:]

.
.
.

def dagger = [:]
dagger.runtime = "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger"
dagger.android = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$versions.dagger"
dagger.android_support = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$versions.dagger"
dagger.compiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$versions.dagger"
dagger.android_processor = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$versions.dagger"
deps.dagger = dagger

def kotlin = [:]
kotlin.stdlib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$versions.kotlin"
kotlin.plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin"
kotlin.allopen = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$versions.kotlin"
deps.kotlin = kotlin

.
.
.

ext.deps = deps

def build_versions = [:]
build_versions.min_sdk = 26
build_versions.target_sdk = 33
ext.build_versions = build_versions
```